# GY6 scooter spark plug getting voltage, but no spark?

Tags: electrical, sparkplugs, scooter, spark, stator

I have a gy6 scooter that's not getting any spark, but I've done troubleshooting on the whole system (except the stator) and I can't find anything wrong.

Every part I've checked from the stator power out to the CDI to the ignition coil down to the spark plug has resistance at rest or has voltage when turning over the engine.

But the spark plug just doesn't spark (and I've tried 2 new spark plugs).

If I put 1 multimeter pin on the tip of the spark plug center electrode, and the other pin on a grounded part of the engine, I get some voltage when turning over the engine. This leads me to believe that the stator doesn't need replacing.

Is it possible it's the stator? And what else could it be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you checked the clearance between the stator and the pickup? There needs to be about a paper's width clearance between the two. It just may need adjusting.